gem install bundler -v 2.3.26 0.334 ERROR: SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate
I create a dockerfile to install ruby 2.6.3 and rails 6.1.3.2
0.334 ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
0.334 ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
0.433 ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
0.433 ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
0.538 ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
0.538 ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
0.540 ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (= 2.3.26), here is why:
0.540           Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate) (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
0.635 ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
0.635 ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store
0.731 ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 1: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
0.731 ERROR:  You must add /OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign to your local trusted store

Please help me
Install the framework to build project

There are plenty of resources to assist with this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70066289/ssl-verification-error-when-running-gem-install-bundler-on-fresh-macbookpro-m1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76807740/ssl-verification-error-at-depth-0-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-20, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71798420/why-i-get-ssl-errors-while-installing-packages-on-dockeron-mac, https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2231, etc. Could be an openssl issue, the need to install ca-certificates, a rubygems version issue, or.... but those links should help you.

Update to rails 6.1.7.8 and Ruby 3.0.7 if you can.  It's usually outdated software that causes these issues.
